# QuickBooks Online sparce Invoice XML update stopped working

Tags: quickbooks-online

My clients QBO update stopped working a month ago after 2 years of working.
The API Explorer seemed to be all JSON now.   I noticed that the endpoint changed from the finance one to https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com.

I could get My XML payloads to work but changing the content type to "application/xml" in the API Explorer. I also had to add &minorversion=4 to the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the post.  I was unable to get the formatting to work here so I took a screen shot.
[image: Post]